# How to check if float is approximately an integer

Tags: python, floating-point

In Python, how can I check if a floating point number is approximately a whole number, with a user-specified maximum difference?

I am thinking of something like `is_whole(f, eps)`, where `f` is the value in question and `eps` is the allowed maximum deviation, with the following results:

```
>>> is_whole(1.1, 0.05)
False
>>> is_whole(1.1, 0.2)
True
>>> is_whole(-2.0001, 0.01)
True
```

Comment: Downvote without comment? Nothing I can do to improve then...

Answer (score 5):

One solution I came up with is

```
def is_whole(f, eps):
    return abs(f - round(f)) < abs(eps)
```

but I am not sure if there is a more pythonic way to do this.

**EDIT**

Use `abs(eps)` instead of just `eps` to avoid silent misbehavior.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for your hint, I've changed the function a little.

Comment: it is hard to get more pythonic than a natural 1-line function

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just write a function doing this myself.

```
def is_whole(f, eps):
    whole_number = round(f)
    deviation = abs(eps)
    return whole_number - deviation <= f <= whole_number + deviation
```

I wrote this on the fly, if there are mistakes please tell me!
Hope I could help.